# Missing value for primary key id on App\Entity symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

My relation between 2 entities is a `OneToOne` relation.

1) User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var $userContact
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserContact" ,  inversedBy="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id",  nullable=false)
     **/
    private $userContact;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $last_name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $last_name): self
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

2. UserContact Entity:

```
class UserContact
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;  

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="UserContact")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $mobile_number;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUserId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function setUserId(int $user_id): self
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobileNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mobile_number;
    }

    public function setMobileNumber(string $mobile_number): self
    {
        $this->mobile_number = $mobile_number;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

My User Repository looks like this:

```
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function index() {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->innerJoin('u.userContact', 'uc')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
 public function index()
    {
       $users = $em->getRepository('App:User')->index();  
       }
```

It's throwing an error like this one:

`Missing value for primary key id on App\Entity\UserContact`

Comment: post your complete `User` and `UserContact` entities

Comment: question has edited. Please check

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe that `OneToOne` expects that column set in `referencedColumnName` (`user_id` in your case) is a Primary Key. Try move (and/or add) `@ORM\Id()` in `UserContact` to `user_id`

Comment: You mean to say add this @ORM\Id() on user_id column. ? user_id is ForeignKey of users table. It will not work because @ORM\Id() is using on multiple columns 1 for its primary key and another for user_id.

Comment: User entities id is primary and user_id on userContact entities is FK of users table.

Comment: that's what I'm saying. Since `OneToOne` requires user_id to be primary key you need to do a hack which is setting composite primary key (with two columns: id and user_id)

Answer (score 2):

In your association, the owning side is `User` and the inverse side is `UserContact`. You must use `mappedBy` for the inverse side instead `inversedBy`. So your annotation for the `$user` attribute in User entity must be this:

`/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="UserContact")
 */
private $user;`

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Comment: what do you mean by owning side ?

Comment: Owning side in a doctrine relationship is the side that has the foreign key. Please see the link i provided in my answer.